# Why does clicking on UP then BACK in GMail App result in returning to Home screen and not My Android App

Tags: android

My current Android Application allows users to send an email using the code below:-

```
   @Suppress("SameParameterValue")
    private fun sendEmail(destinationEmailAddress: String, @StringRes resId: Int) {
        try {
            startActivity(
                Actions.sendEmail(
                    destinationEmailAddress,
                    getString(resId),
                    getString(R.string.feedback_email_message, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, VERSION_NAME)
                )
            )
        } catch (_: Exception) {
            somethingWentWrong(R.string.email_error)
        }
    }
```

with `sendEmail` function resembling:-

```
fun sendEmail(email: String, subject: String = "", message: String = "") =
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        .apply {
            data = Uri.parse(
                "mailto:$email" +
                        "?subject=${Uri.encode(subject)}" +
                        "&body=${Uri.encode(message)}"
            )
        }
```

Using the `BACK` key the user returns to My App.

Using the `UP` key within Gmail they are first presented with their inbox, then they only have the option of using the `BACK` key, which returns them to the Home screen of the device.
My App is still "active" in the recents page.

How can I achieve the desired result of always returning the user to my App whether they use the `BACK` key or `UP` & `BACK` key combination?

Comment: what is UP key ?

Comment: The arrow at top left hand corner in toolbar, when you are composing an email using the Gmail app

Comment: How about startActivityForResult?

Comment: @ytRino I tried that (although startActivityForResult is deprecated, I used the new contract launch() however that still doesnt give the desired experience

Comment: Can you show us a gif of what's happening on up and back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change how Gmail's Up button works. In fact, it is working exactly how the Up button is intended to work as per [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#the_up_button_never_exits_your_app):

> When your app is launched using a deep link on another app's task, Up transitions users back to your app’s task and through a simulated back stack and **not to the app that triggered the deep link.** The Back button, however, does take you back to the other app.

It is absolutely expected that the Up button keeps the user in Gmail in Gmail's task (i.e., Gmail's entry in the Recents menu). That is the core difference between Up and Back.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, So theres no approach I can take to achieve returning my user to my App when they use UP -> BACK?

Comment: Correct, there is no approach you can take for that case. Hitting the Up button switches from your task stack (i.e., your app on the back stack with Gmail on top) to Gmail's task (which only has Gmail - your app isn't part of the back stack of that task).

Answer (score -1):

The `Back Key` is always managged programically and is used to bring back user from other Avtivity or Fragmnet to the MainPage and it's part of the UI/UX design.

Most of the time the `Back Key` is just a replica of `Up Key`, like in Gmail app that when ever you navigate to a secondry Activity/Fragment a back key appear some where (Mostly top left of the screen) to help you navigate back to the Main Screen.

What you really need to do is to `Implement Custom Back Navigation` for `Up Key`.

To achive this goal you should understand the concept of Android Tasks and Back Stack, A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when performing a certain job. The activities are arranged in a stack—the back stack)—in the order in which each activity is opened.

For example, an email app might have one activity to show a list of new messages. When the user selects a message, a new activity opens to view that message. This new activity is added to the back stack. If the user presses the Back button, that new activity is finished and popped off the stack. This [video](https://youtu.be/MvIlVsXxXmY) provides a good overview of how the back stack works.

When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus. The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped. When an activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user interface.

When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored).

[image: A representation of how each new activity in a task adds an item to the back stack. When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is destroyed and the previous activity resumes.]

In your case what you need to do is "Provide custom back navigation"

You might want to override the default Back button behavior to allow the user to navigate back through their web browsing history instead of the previous screens in your app.

So you should Implement Custom Back Navigation.

[ComponentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity), the base class for [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity) and [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity), allows you to control the behavior of the Back button by using its `OnBackPressedDispatcher`, which you can retrieve by calling `getOnBackPressedDispatcher()`.

The `OnBackPressedDispatcher` controls how Back button events are dispatched to one or more `OnBackPressedCallback` objects. The constructor for `OnBackPressedCallback` takes a boolean for the initial enabled state. Only when a callback is enabled (i.e., `isEnabled()` returns true) will the dispatcher call the callback's `handleOnBackPressed()` to handle the Back button event. You can change the enabled state by calling `setEnabled()`.

Callbacks are added via the addCallback methods. It is strongly recommended to use the `addCallback()` method which takes a [LifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner). This ensures that the `OnBackPressedCallback` is only added when the `LifecycleOwner` is Lifecycle.State.STARTED. The activity also removes registered callbacks when their associated `LifecycleOwner` is destroyed, which prevents memory leaks and makes it suitable for use in fragments or other lifecycle owners that have a shorter lifetime than the activity.

Here's an example callback implementation:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // Handle the back button event
        }

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in the lambda
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to do it in Activity [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#onBackPressed()) to handle Back button events, It's recommend using a [OnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback) instead. However, if you are unable to make this change, the following rules apply:

- All callbacks registered via addCallback are evaluated when you call super.onBackPressed().
- onBackPressed is always called, regardless of any registered
  instances of OnBackPressedCallback.

Comment: They're asking to change the functionality of the Up button **in Gmail,** not the button in their own app.